# Teste de carga de cadastro não persiste na base de dados

Tags: testes, testes-funcionais

Estou utilizando o jmeter e realizei o seguinte procedimento:

- Realizei a gravação de um script em uma funcionalidade de cadastro de usuário;
- Fiz a extração dos ViewStates (pois se trata de uma funcionalidade com paginas em web flow);
- Rodei o teste;

Ocorrido:

Ao gravar o teste o usuário foi salvo normalmente na base de dados. Apaguei o usuário e executei o script gravado. Não houve erros no script, porém o usuário não foi salvo. Alguem pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: a tabela esta auto-increment? pois se você esta fazendo um insert passando o valor da pk, ele só insere uma vez depois da erro de duplicidade e não insere o repetido.

Answer (score 1):

## Verifique outras tabelas

É possível que a funcionalidade em questão grave dados em outra(s) tabela(s) e haja algum registro. O sistema, vendo que algo já existe, não grava o usuário.

## Erro "mascarado"

Outra possibilidade é estar ocorrendo um erro, mas o seu teste não está pegando isso.

Seria interessante olhar cuidadosamente o log de retorno de cada requisição.

## Cache do sistema

Se o sistema possui algum tipo de cache, pode ser que ele tenha uma versão do usuário em memória e pense que ele já existe.

Esse cenário é bem estranho, mas pode ocorrer dependendo de como o sistema gerencia suas entidades. Uma lógica incorreta usando a API JPA do Java pode levar a esse tipo de problema.

## Confusão de ambiente

Também ocorre algumas vezes de olharmos a base de dados ou tabela incorreta.

Na dúvida, verifique com o responsável pelo ambiente se houve alguma alteração. Pode ser que alguém tenha configurado o sistema para usar outra instância do servidor de banco de dados.

## Registro "perdido"

Outra possibilidade é que o usuário tenha sido gravado durante o segundo teste, mas você não o encontrou porque o ID ou algum campo usado no critério de consulta mudou.

Isso é comum de ocorrer se houver campos gerados automaticamente pelo sistema.

## Considerações finais

Tentei enumerar acima os problemas mais comuns que ocorrem em cenários onde parece não haver uma explicação razoável

Entretanto, o problema pode estar tanto no equívoco mais básico, como olhar o banco errado, como nos detalhes mais "obscuros" da arquitetura do sistema.

Se nada disso lhe ajudar, resta fazer um trabalho em conjunto com o desenvolvedor do sistema, que pode depurar o comportamento exato do programa. Lembrando que em situações assim é imprescindível detalhar bem o procedimento para reprodução do problema.

Comment: A funcionalidade segue o seguinte processo:
Portal do Sistema > link Cadastre-se > Aceite dos termos > Dados pessoais para cadastro > Agendamento da prova > Questionario pessoal > Finalizacao do cadastro

Cada uma desses passos eh uma pagina diferente em web flow. Percebi que em cada execução no jmeter, a response está trazendo sempre o html do "Aceite dos Termos" em todas as requisições a partir dela. Sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: @LauroMarquesdaRocha Geralmente isso ocorre quando há um erro de validação e a mesma página é carregada com a mensagem. Você deve imprimir o conteúdo da página (html) e analisar para ver o que há lá que não estava na tela original.